# How does docker pull work when there are tags with multiple digests (for os/arch)

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I was wondering how does docker pull work (specifically from docker hub)
When i was looking at a tag of an image e.g [nodejs image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/node/library/node/lts-alpine3.9/images/sha256-5ece590312d73d14e98af26b626f7c41da3a40c1d0c659f053705a3028139094) and noticed the os/arch in there there were multiple.
When i run docker pull how does it choose which one to get?

Comment: Does this article help?: https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/b/tools-software-ides-blog/posts/deploying-multi-architecture-docker-registry

Answer (score 1):

Multi-arch images are built into the Dockerfile/manifests. At build time the respective arch files are copied over, and when pulling, the daemon determines which to use.

Here's a reference of the actual process of building a multi-arch image:

https://lobradov.github.io/Building-docker-multiarch-images/#how-does-it-work

When you're looking at a page like you linked, where you can select an arch from the drop-down, that's showing the list of available archs that the image maintainer added to that image via the process mentioned in the link I referenced.

Comment: So basically the daemon will pull the correct os/arch for which his running on?